# Ionic Angular / Why is the Service not called until controller function ends

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-promise

Mystery for me ... I have my controller and my services.
Why is the service LocalDataService.getCacheUserUpdate(); not launched in it ? Here is some code details.
I modified the code to follow the same pattern as the chatsUpdate but the LocalDataService.getCacheUserUpdate(); gets skipped all the time when I debug step by step... but it is triggered after the function pull refresh is complete

Thanks!

My controller:

```
// Check for new updates in conversations and return the number of new messages
  var getChatsUpdates = function() {
    DataService.getHasNewMessages().success(function(response) {
      $scope.chatsUpdates = response.chats_updates;
      //console.log($scope.chatsUpdates)
    });
  };

  var updateUser = function() {
    LocalDataService.getCacheUserUpdate().success(function(response) {
      $scope.user = [];
      $scope.user = DataService.getUser();
    }).error(function() {
      console.log('error on userupdate')
    })
  }

  var updateUserFreeStatus = function() {
    updateUser()
    $scope.user_free_status = [];
    $scope.user_free_status = DataService.getUserFreeStatus();
  }

  $scope.doHomeRefresh = function() {
    console.log('Start refreshing!')
    updateUserFreeStatus()
    getChatsUpdates()
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    $scope.$apply()
    console.log('refreshed!')
  };
```

And my service:

```
.factory('LocalDataService', function(WebService, $localstorage) {
    return {
        getCacheUserUpdate: function() {
            var userUpdate = WebService.get('profile/get/user/update');

            userUpdate.success(function(response) {
                $localstorage.unset('user')
                console.log(response.user)
                $localstorage.setObject('user', response.user)
            });
            return userUpdate;
        }
        };
})
.factory('DataService', function($q, $localstorage, WebService) {


  return {
    getUser: function() {
        return $localstorage.getObject('user');
    },
    // get updates to check if new messages in conversations
    getHasNewMessages: function() {
        var updates = WebService.get('conversations/updates/new-messages');
        updates.success(function(response) {
            // nothing
        });
        updates.error(function(response) {
            console.log('error in get messages: ' + response)
        });
        return updates;
    }    
  };
})
```

I really don't get what is happening there...

Comment: You need to use a promise object see documentation for $q

Comment: @EmanuelRalha you mean just add $q in the factory function variables ?.factory('LocalDataService', function($q, WebService, $localstorage) {}) ?

Answer (score 2):

As Emanual Ralha said, your webservice needs to return promise objects. Basically speaking:

```
var foo = $http.get('http://localhost/potatoes/1')
```

doesn't actually put the results of the HTTP call into foo, because that will take a while to finish up, and that's not how javascript actually works.

Instead, foo is a promise to a value- you need to do

```
$http.get().then(function(data) {
    $scope.potato = data.data;
});
```

In that situation, the callback function gets invoked when the $http is done (it is synonymous with .success, but .success is nonstandard, so get used to .then and .catch), and you can deal with the results at that point.

Comment: Thanks, this works to have the function run asynchronously but I need to make sure it is finished before stoping the refresh function. Is this where I should use the dfd resolve the promise? Or? I basically need the result to be transmitted to my local scope which it is not right now on the first refresh but only on the second

Comment: When you're using javascript stuff like this, everything has to be asynchronous. So instead of waiting for the async to be complete before returning, you should return a promise for completion. Then, in the calling function, instead of assuming that the function is done when it is called (it isn't, since async), take the returned promise and chain a .then(function()) on to it. Put the stuff that relies on the earlier work being completed in the then() block, and if there's more async, return a promise out of that then block and chain another then().